# Does inplace matter when we return ReLU(x)

Tags: python, pytorch, in-place

Is there a difference between the following two classes?
I know what inplace is (you don't need to do `x = function(x)` but only `function(x)` to modify `x` if inplace is `True`). But here because we `return self.conv(x)`, it should not matter, right?

```
class ConvBlock(nn.Module):

    def __init__(
        self,
        in_channels,
        out_channels,
        down=True,
        use_act=True,
        **kwargs
        ):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Sequential((nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels,
                                  padding_mode='reflect',
                                  **kwargs) if down else nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels,
                                  out_channels, **kwargs)),
                                  nn.InstanceNorm2d(out_channels),
                                  (nn.ReLU() if use_act else nn.Identity()))

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv(x)


class ConvBlockInplace(nn.Module):

    def __init__(
        self,
        in_channels,
        out_channels,
        down=True,
        use_act=True,
        **kwargs
        ):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Sequential((nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels,
                                  padding_mode='reflect',
                                  **kwargs) if down else nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels,
                                  out_channels, **kwargs)),
                                  nn.InstanceNorm2d(out_channels),
                                  (nn.ReLU(inplace=True) if use_act else nn.Identity()))

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv(x)
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga There's nn.ReLU(inplace=True) instead of nn.ReLU() in the second class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inplace` operations do the exact amount of computations. However, there are less memory accesses, if your task is memory bound. Then, it would matter.

---

I used [the `ptflops` flops counter](https://github.com/sovrasov/flops-counter.pytorchhttps://github.com/sovrasov/flops-counter.pytorch) to generate the following statistics

```
ConvBlock(
  0.0 M, 100.000% Params, 0.015 GMac, 100.000% MACs, 
  (conv): Sequential(
    0.0 M, 100.000% Params, 0.015 GMac, 100.000% MACs, 
    (0): Conv2d(0.0 M, 100.000% Params, 0.014 GMac, 93.333% MACs, 3, 10, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding_mode=reflect)
    (1): InstanceNorm2d(0.0 M, 0.000% Params, 0.0 GMac, 3.333% MACs, 10, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=False, track_running_stats=False)
    (2): ReLU(0.0 M, 0.000% Params, 0.0 GMac, 3.333% MACs, )
  )
)
Computational complexity:       0.01 GMac
Number of parameters:           280     
Warning: module ConvBlockInplace is treated as a zero-op.
ConvBlockInplace(
  0.0 M, 100.000% Params, 0.015 GMac, 100.000% MACs, 
  (conv): Sequential(
    0.0 M, 100.000% Params, 0.015 GMac, 100.000% MACs, 
    (0): Conv2d(0.0 M, 100.000% Params, 0.014 GMac, 93.333% MACs, 3, 10, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding_mode=reflect)
    (1): InstanceNorm2d(0.0 M, 0.000% Params, 0.0 GMac, 3.333% MACs, 10, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=False, track_running_stats=False)
    (2): ReLU(0.0 M, 0.000% Params, 0.0 GMac, 3.333% MACs, inplace=True)
  )
)
Computational complexity:       0.01 GMac
Number of parameters:           280
```

Comment: Thanks, just to make sure, I cannot do self.conv(x) to refresh x if inplace isn't True ? EDIT: just tested it and the answer is yes (actually, i can still call self.conv(x) but it just doesn't change x)